# Why does my old folium app stopped show maps

Tags: pyqt5, folium

A few months ago I did my first folium project and I even looked for help here with full success :)
Now I am trying going back to this and develop this app but somehow the same code dodnt work anymore. It shows bank map and I have now idea why. Any ideas or tips?

```py
import io
import sys

import folium
from folium.plugins.draw import Draw
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor

class Mapy(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.interfejs()

    def interfejs(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        interceptor = Interceptor()
        self.webEngineView.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)

        self.webEngineView.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self.handle_downloadRequested)
        self.loadPage()
        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("mapy")
        self.show()

    def loadPage(self):
        m = folium.Map(location=[51.7687323, 19.4569911], zoom_start=5)
        Draw(
            export=True,
            filename="my_data.geojson",
            position="topleft",
            draw_options={
                "polyline": False,
                "rectangle": False,
                "circle": False,
                "circlemarker": False,
            },
            edit_options={"poly": {"allowIntersection": False}},
        ).add_to(m)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())

    def handle_downloadRequested(self, item):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", item.suggestedFileName()
        )
        if path:
            item.setPath(path)
            item.accept()

class Interceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        info.setHttpHeader(b"Accept-Language", b"en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,de;q=0.7")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    okno = Mapy()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: add `interceptor = Interceptor()` `self.webEngineView.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)` after `self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()`

Comment: I fixed code like it should be (I think but its still not working) any ideas why? or what I did wrong?

Comment: I get the following: https://i.imgur.com/JpgNoq1.png . What version of python, pyqt5, folium do you use? What is your OS? Could you put a picture of what you get

Comment: Im using latest macos, pyton 3.7.3 and folium 0.12.1 pytq5 5.15.2 and get this: https://ibb.co/bBpvZC7

Comment: Try updating to pyqt5 5.15.4 and pyqtwebengine 5.15.4: `python -m pip install pyqt5==5.15.4 pyqtwebengine==5.15.4`

Comment: Still the same. I even check on linux with python 3.9.2 folium 0.11 and pyqt5 5.15.2. The same. So I upgraded all those on linux and .... the same :/ how its possible?

Comment: I use linux with the most updated versions and it works correctly. Maybe you don't have any firewall activated? Have you tried on another network?

Comment: No I didnt try. Im on iphone hotspot so no firewall is possible

Comment: I recommend you try it on a home network, iphone could be restricting some requests.

Comment: I just tried update folium and it upgrade dependencies (idna) and now everything works :D